# eval() function in java script throwing error with direct value

Tags: javascript, string

I tried to evaluate string function `toString()` in console. 
In one scenario it is working fine and in another scenario it is not working as expected.

Scenario 1:

```
eval(99.toString());
```

output:

```
Invalid or unexpected token ...
```

Scenario 2:

```
var a = 99;
eval(a.toString());
```

Output:

```
99
```

Please help me to understand the difference between both the scenarios.[image]

Comment: `toString` is not the same as `toString()`

Comment: You need to surround `99.toString()` with parentheses like this: `(99).toString()`

Comment: If you observe 99 is a numeric value, It can be 99.00 or 99.11 etc. So you cannot use to string directly on numbers. You can use it by "99".toString() or (99).toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `eval`.

The error is produced by `99.toString`. The reason is that `99.` is read as a number (equivalent to `99.0`) and then `toString` is just a random word that doesn't fit the syntax:

```
99.0 toString  // what the parser sees
```

To fix it, you need to keep `.` from being treated as part of the number. For example:

```
99 .toString()    // numbers can't contain spaces, so '99' and '.' are read separately
(99).toString()   // the ')' token prevents '.' from being read as part of the number
99.0.toString()   // '99.0' is read as a number, then '.toString' is the property access
99..toString()    // same as above, just with '99.' as the number
99['toString']()  // using [ ] for property access, no '.' at all
```

Answer (score 0):

A numeric literall (`99`) is not and object with properties. A variable with value 99 like `var x = 99` is and object and you can use methods like `x.toString()`

Answer (score -1):

eval expects a script input (string), in example:

```js
var x = eval('var a = 99; a.toString()');
console.log(x);
```